# Can anyone help me to create Dockerfile for my tomcat copy?

Tags: tomcat, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I can not use default copy of tomcat because I have some depended jar file which I have to put in tomcat lib folder.

What image can I use in order to have the right dependencies into Tomcat lib?

Comment: Please clarify your issue and provide more details...

Comment: use an external volume with your project files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make your own Dockerfile (`FROM` the [official tomcat image](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/), like the [8.5 one for instance](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/b0cb4ee4d375ade382d77c450903b7c3a0c2b39f/8.5/jre8/Dockerfile)) which will copy that dependent jar into tomcat lib folder:

```
FROM tomcat:8.5
EXPOSE 8080
COPY your/dependent/jar /path/to/tomcat/lib
# For instance
COPY your/dependent/jar /usr/share/tomcat8/lib
```